Can we judge morality?
I often see moral realists claim, 'Relative morality is wrong because objective morality exists.'
I think this answer is problematic, because relativists can claim the opposite: 'Objective morality is wrong because relative morality exists.'
This circular reasoning can lead to self-referential paradoxes.
So, is there any kind of judgment we can use to determine whether a moral view is right or wrong?
Since relativists also claim that their morality doesn't require consistency, I think we cannot say that a relativist's contradictory moral foundations are inherently wrong, as they follow from their relativistic axioms.

First of all, that's not reasoning; it's each side stating its position. Second, even if it were reasoning, it wouldn't be circular. Another person can't make my argument circular by disagreeing with it.

Perhaps the whole philosophy of ethics goal is to morph the relative-subjective onto the intersubjective fixing the landscape, not unlike contemporary philosophy of language's private language argument hints that the very establishment and use of a public language fixing the semiotic linguistic landscape is intrinsically intersubjective thus objective, even for the use of a single human on an island? Of course this doesn't forbid polysemy uses of word at all due to the always-existing relative context, though sometimes some audience will get confused which is just a technical side effect...

Can you re-phrase that? Many; perhaps most of us 'judge morality' every day.
Who claims 'Relative morality is wrong because objective morality exists' is welcome to define 'objective morality…'
The judgment you should use to determine whether a moral view is right or wrong is how it compares to your up-bringing… first, to family and then to your societal values. Is that difficult?
Who says morality doesn't require consistency is welcome to explain…
Without details, why would anyone mind a relativist's contradictory moral foundations being inherently wrong?

Most people conceptualize morality in primal religious terms: as a set of concrete rules handed down by some higher authority that must be observed with a degree of austerity. Moral realists might construe that higher authority differently: as coming from one or another religion or philosophy, or as a syncretic rule-set gleaned from many religions or philosophies. Moral relativists might reject some or all of these higher authorities and rule-sets, and create an eclectic (hodgepodge or analytic) set of rules. But both groups take the principle of concrete rules as canon to be embraced or opposed.
The issue here is that moral reasoning is actually intersubjective and developmental. We have to learn it from others, we have to come into agreement with it, and we have to consistently revise it with experience. I don't mean to say that objective morality doesn't exist, but if it does it is akin to a strange attractor, which pulls us towards itself but cannot be perfectly captured in word or deed. We just get better at it.
Honestly, this is a large part of why people are aggravated by moral and ethical philosophy. Most people don't want to think about it, because thinking about moral behavior takes time and effort, and entails the unpleasant emotions of remorse and regret. Most people just want someone to tell them what is and isn't moral so they know what to do when they feel like being moral (and know what to atone for when they don't). But most people also get annoyed if someone tells them moral rules they don't want to hear, or that come from a source they don't want to listen to, or that puts them on the spot and makes them think about themselves too much. So people tend to take the moral rules they like as objectively true, condemn other moral rules as subjective nonsense, and squabble endlessly with anyone who disagrees.
C'est la vie…

It's like looking through the entrance door of a well known but darkened room, what among the clutter of furnishing and decoration can still be recognized and has it been moved about much. To prevent excessive toe stubbings.

History shows that both camps of relativists and objectivists exist since centuries and continue existing today.
Therefore: Until now no accepted criterion to judge, which position is right, has been found.
Nevertheless there are specific moral norms which are hold at both sides, e.g., the Golden Rule.

I'm not sure the Golden Rule retains its validity in a relativistic setting, because it falls apart at the borders between different relativistic systems; one community of people with one relativist moral view may wish to be treated differently to another community and vice versa.

@ConnieMnemonic For people who know they are different, different than other people: Pay attention with the Golden Rule ... :-)

Isn't this essentially a Bandwagon argument, that "most people think this, therefore it's true?" You're saying that throughout history, a proportion of people do not agree with something, therefore that thing is not true.

In the social sphere, if not everyone agrees with the decision at the decision point (there may be regret later as new information accumulates) it isn't untrue, but it is a weakness. If a universal, it means everyone is on side.

The golden rule is a heuristic rule that asks people (especially children) to exercise empathy - based on the assumption that we all have more or less the same preferences. This is fine as far as it goes, in basic cases - it highlights the role of reciprocity and empathy. But in actual moral dilemmas this rule seems pretty worthless. Also, as a matter of fact, people do have different preferences. (Should I never give birthday gifts just because I don't care about receiving any myself? Etc.)


So, is there any kind of judgment we can use to determine whether a moral view is right or wrong?

Every moral framework provides such a mechanism internal to the framework (utilitarianism, for example).
As for choosing between frameworks or between realism and relativism, not yet.

Issue 1
The nature of the counter-argument.

I often see moral realists claim, 'Relative morality is wrong because objective morality exists.' I think this answer is problematic, because relativists can claim the opposite: 'Objective morality is wrong because relative morality exists.' This circular reasoning can lead to self-referential paradoxes.

Emphasis mine. This is just a quick thing I wanna touch on, the meat of what I'm saying is in Issue 2 below. I see a logical issue in the argument "I have problems with [Statement A] because somebody claimed [Contradictory Statement]."
The mere existence of a contradictory argument to a theory is not an argument against that theory. By that logic, the fact "Flat Earthers exist" would itself be an argument against the Earth being round.
Issue 2
What does it mean to exist?

'Objective morality is wrong because relative morality exists.'

I'm not quoting the above as something you yourself are stating, just as a statement to pick apart.
The statements "Objective morality exists" and "Relative morality exists" are saying two quite dramatically different things:
What are the objectivists saying?

"Objective morality exists."

This statement is trying to express that objective morality has its own existence in some form, like gravity and rocks and dreams. That objective morality itself has some quality of being. Often the argument is that this being is embodied in God. For transparency, this is my personal position.
What are the relativists saying?

"Relative morality exists."

This statement is saying something quite different. In this context, what is actually being said is:

"People who practice and believe in relative morality exist."

Why is that a problem?
Relativistic morality cannot be said to exist in an objective sense, because if it did, it wouldn't be relativistic morality.
Even if you stretch the argument to the wildest limits, the closest you could get is:

"The true, existing objective morality is to be morally relativistic."

Which is, unfortunately, moral objectivism.
(EDIT: You'll also notice it's self-contradictory. If objective morality is to be relativistic, then when you're relativistic in compliance with that, aren't you actually being objectivist?)
Wrapping it up
When relativists claim relative morality exists, they are not using the word "exists" in the same way objectivists are using it.
Furthermore, when attempts are made to use "exists" by the same definition as objectivists, self-contradiction emerges. If relative morality truly exists in a real, tangible way, it is no longer relative; it is objective.

I think relativist view accept inconsistent moral judging because it based on context of moral act, then it would be pointless if we say that "Relativistic view of moral is wrong because relativistic are not objective". In my sense its like "Human walk is wrong, because fish swim"

I think also that you could be right that two of my statement have an issue, maybe its my bad to add in here. But, my point is actually is there any kind of judgment that we can judge that moral view right or not

From an objectivist perspective, it's more as if I had a stick that was 3cm long, and someone said, "No, it's 4cm long." Objectively, it's 3cm long and they're wrong. What you're asking is, "How do we know what is right and wrong? How do we find the stick? Can we even know if there is a stick?" @MuhammadLuthfiArkanKamil

From my perspective, as a Catholic, I believe that God sets, and in fact is that moral standard. We have an intuitive understanding of some of it, not all of it, and need God to get the whole picture. But of course, others would disagree. @MuhammadLuthfiArkanKamil

Unfortunately the relativist doesn't need to say "The true, existing objective morality is to be morally relativistic" in order to be a relativist.

@Matthias Quite so. They need only deny the existence of objective morality or any power it may have over us. Which is more coherent an argument, but does leave the relativist in a difficult position when it comes to condemning atrocities.

@ConnieMnemonic hm I guess they can still condemn atrocities, just not from a moral ground. They can say "I don't like that and I'm going to thwart it" which is simple force of will and entirely subjective but nonetheless valid to those who feel the same way. Because in lieu of reason, feelings are truth.

@Matthias Pretty much. It may be such a person condemns an atrocity, but they would be unable to justify it beyond "Because I don't like it." I personally think that's a problem, because if everyone operated that way, we'd be unable to actually construct a rational answer to the society-wide question, "Why is murder bad?"

The meta-ethical views of relativism and objectivism do not (in all interpretations) contradict each other.

In some situations I might accept that it's morally justified to lie. For instance, because this would save someone else's (or my own) life. While in other cases, I might not find lying acceptable. So, "do not lie" is a moral principle that can only be applied relative to particular situations. Yet, in situations where it does apply it might be seen (by anyone in a group) as compelling, as compelling as empirical observation -- and in that sense "objective".
Rational, reasonable people -- even in the same society, sharing the same overall cultural values, or at least very similar values, possibly even the same religion -- may, given 'all the facts', still come to evaluate those facts differently, or come to weigh the applicability of different moral norms differently. (Notable examples are Supreme Court cases where majority and minority opinions conflict.) This seems to imply that even if we share a set of moral or legal principles -- in other words, if those principles are objective, at least in sofar as they are intersubjectively shared and accepted --, we can still come to different conclusions. In other words, the actual judgment may still be relative to us.

Relativism and objectivism each express true facts, I believe. Relativism expresses that moral concepts change through time, and are different relative to one's culture and outlook on life, relative to particular situations, a particular way of representing and framing what we consider to be 'the truth, the whole truth and nothing but the truth'. Objectivism expresses that moral values are always intersubjective, shared in a group, and experienced as very (though not absolutely) compelling. We don't learn morality from reading philosophy. Moral values are acquired -- in sofar as they are acquired -- by childhood experience. As adults we only have a very limited power to re-educate ourselves (not that people haven't tried).

I feel like this answer conflates objectivism and absolutism. You don't need relativism to incorporate context into objectivist decision making.

@ConnieMnemonic - The way I presented it here is indeed rather ambiguous. I don't think I conflate objectivism and absolutism, though. I'm basically saying that some form of "objectivism" can go along with relativism. (Not some absolutist belief in the Patonic "Good", of course.) I'm also saying that pretty strong forms of relativism -- across time and cultures -- are empirically given and that there is no principled way to take some kind of stand outside and evaluate them. Society, education, and ideologies change together. ...

So, I do mean more by "relativism" then merely "dependence on context". Even with full knowledge of the context, reasonable people can still come to different, contradictory evaluations of what one should do or is permitted to do. And I don't see a way to mediate or "resolve" those contradictions -- that is, no moral way. What we happen to do is to apply some kind of majority rule, given a jury or some judicial experts -- but that's basically an affirmation of inescapable relativism, I think.

That's part of what I'm pointing to I think. I'm not convinced they're compatible ideas; in an objective moral system, there is always a correct path. Our ability to see it or carry it out is the limiting factor.

@ConnieMnemonic - Yes, I guess that is what many people mean by "objective" - But that's an illusion in my eyes. It's the Platonist/realist view of moral good/right. I believe moral values are only "objective" in sofar as they are intersubjectively shared and/or experienced as compelling. Also, there is imo clearly an aspect of creation/arbitrariness to those values -- just as in esthetic values.

Also, most people really don't care (and there is no moral need to care) about these meta-ethical issues. Similar to how in math, it doesn't matter that much whether you're a realist or an intuitionist (at least not for most subfields, afaik).

Well, it's something of a matter of perspective. If you're a relativist, there's no moral need to care. If you're an objectivist, there is.

The question has a few issues. Let's look at them and try to reach a resolution.
The two statements

"relative morality exists"

A clearer way to phrase this is: "relative morality is the case", or better: "morality is relative". So, rephrased, the statement becomes:

"Objective morality is wrong because morality is relative."

This is not circular, but it is an argument based on a claim. The issue is, the claim is unsupported here.
It's also a negative claim, which is technically a fallacy. You can never say "there is no evidence for X"; you can only say "I don't know of any evidence for X". Simplified: "there is no X" is correctly stated as "I don't know of any X". This fallacy is called Argument from Silence, or Argument from Ignorance (depending on how offensive you want to be).
So the relativist is in a tough place arguing a negative claim. They can only claim agnosticism, saying "I don't know of any evidence for objective morality, therefore I conclude that there is none. And in absence of objective morality, morality can only be relative". This is a reasonable conclusion given the premise (lack of objective morality).
Examining the claim of the moral realist:

"Relative morality is wrong because objective morality exists."

This contains a positive claim: "objective morality exists". Positive claims are not negative claims, so they don't suffer from the problems of the Argument from Silence fallacy. However, claims need to be supported in order to be convincing.
Here, the claim is asserted without any supporting arguments. However if the claim is granted as a premise, the conclusion is valid. In other words, if objective morality exists, then relative morality is indeed wrong.
And the claim of the relativist is just the same argument flipped and reversed: if there is no objective morality, then morality can only be relative. This is circular in a way, because it's saying the same thing twice. You could just say "there is no objective morality" and it would lose no meaning.
Judging morality

So, is there any kind of judgment we can use to determine whether a moral view is right or wrong?

This question is really going a lot of places all at once. Let's see what we can establish here.
So far it's not defined what "a moral view" is. Is it an opinion that someone has, regarding what should or should not be done by people? Or is it a statement of history like "God said this" which is judged by the presence of evidence and facts supporting it?
Opinions are hard to weigh, because they involve value judgements. To make a conclusion you must first decide what is important. For example, think of the trolley problem: are the lives of five felons worth more than one child? Such value judgements are subjective and have no basis in evidence.
The moral realist can argue a point from history, saying "God said this, therefore this is morality". That claim must then be supported, but at least there's a chance that if it's supported, then morality is established.
Without objective morality, we can only lay out if-then scenarios, establishing "if we do this, then that will happen". These scenarios can be proven. But what you cannot prove is whether the outcome is good or moral  because the definition of those are opinions, in a world where there is no objective morality.
The relativist cannot determine whether a moral view is right or wrong. To the realist they need to only say "I don't believe you", but this isn't calling realism "wrong"; it's only skepticism.
Logical contradiction

Since relativists also claim that their morality doesn't require consistency, I think we cannot say that a relativist's contradictory moral foundations are inherently wrong, as they follow from their relativistic axioms.

Notice that you used the word "wrong", which means you're approaching this from a realist perspective by questioning right or wrong. But from that perspective, by definition, relativism is already wrong. If there is a right and wrong, then relativism is wrong.
But to correct your suggestion: it's absolutely straightforward for a realist to call a relativist wrong, despite the consistency of the relativist's worldview (or consistent lack of consistency).
An error can be consistent and still be an error. Consistency does not indicate truth. Inconsistency is an error but consistency is not necessarily a truth. The best lies are consistent.
The way a moral realist would say that a relativist is wrong is following this structure:

relativism is wrong because realism is right.
realism is right because ...

That's it. This means if realism can't be proven, then there is no argument against relativism. But if it can be proven, then relativism falls. In my opinion the only way to prove realism is to argue from history that a deity ("God") established it, and to argue that based on historical evidence. (This is out of scope for this answer).


... is there any kind of judgment we can use to determine whether a moral view is right or wrong?

Yes, but not in isolation from all other moral rules.
That is, abortion or human-cloning cannot be considered independently of all other rules. Morals is a set of rules that serve a goal, and the goal is not reachable by following a sub-group of such rules.
Now, which goal?
Each human group has its own morals (even if they reject them, we all follow some). Morals are rules that enforce certain behaviors in order to keep peace, have better interactions, preserve values, blah blah, etc. And what is all that for? If there's no peace, if interactions degrade, if values are lost, etc., the human group tends to self-destruct.
So, in final terms, the goal of moral rules is survival (see: Hobbes[to prevent social collapse], Hume[social harmony], Darwin[evolutionary advantages for survival], Spencer[survival and stability], Durkheim[survival of societies], etc.).
Is there a standard recipe for survival?
No. Each human group implement different moral rules, and each human group is subject to natural selection.
In other words, groups that tend to survive are those which morals are consistent with natural selection.
For your question:
a) in common societies, the moral view that killing humans is bad is right because it normally improves group survival.
b) But in some groups, where other rules don't prevent social damage inflicted by criminals, and instead, it encourage criminality, it is necessary to kill criminals. But if they follow the same rule (killing humans is bad), the social group ends up collapsing.
So

A moral view tends to be right within a group of moral rules if the social group tends to survival.
A group that tends to collapse is not because a single moral rule, but due to the whole set of moral rules.

Europe is a great example. It would seem that european morals are at the top. However, european societies tend to collapse, because their moral rules (which include avoiding reproduction, isolating, keep language barriers and embracing wokeness), as a whole, are quickly destroying societies (which implies that territories will be occupied by others with "better" moral rules). So, allowing strangers to freely enter Europe could be a good rule in isolation, while the whole set of moral rules is proving to be destructive. This case is amazing: those who seem replacing europeans are... africans and arabs! (which implies that their morals are pragmatically better from the perspective of natural selection). See https://www.newsweek.com/europe-population-decline-crisis-1995599

Doesn't this outlook tend towards the... eugenics-y?

The objectivist Christian would disagree with that definition of morality. To us, the goal of morality is not survival; it is "to know God (and his son Jesus Christ that he sent)". This is the ultimate good, and survival is secondary. However, this answer is a great representation of the relativist perspective.

The moral realist has their work cut out for them.
From a conceptual viewpoint, they need to explain:

Why people have different morals?
Why some are right and others wrong ?
How do they know their criteria are correct for (2) ?

There are also empirical/evidential challenges to moral realism:
Compare:

If there are no objective morals, we'd expect to see a diversity of moral systems that are not mutually consistent, since they would result from unique experiences and histories of the people involved.


If there are objective morals, we'd expect it to manifest in some objective way in the world, and to have objective implications. We also would not be surprised if all societies effectively had the same moral systems.

Point goes to relativism here. Moral systems are all over the place.
Also, even if we all had the same moral systems, you'd need to explain why this isn't just a byproduct of us all having human brains, which evolved certain sensibilities that feel like truths to us? So now you need to find some universal principle that can provably pick out "true morals".

I suspect the main reason for positing objective morals isn't actual evidence but a type of argument from consequences -- if there are no objective morals then I cannot say my morals are right and yours are wrong, which will undercut the authority of our moral systems and weaken their power to control behavior.
However, it seems that the reason we follow morals are due to:

Fear of consequences (primal aversion)
Promise of reward (primal attraction)
Sense of righteousness ("I am right")
Sense of justice ("I am making things right")

Only (3) is really threatened by loss of "objectivity" -- you don't get to be righteous. Oh well!!
1 and 2 are more "base" reasons for following rules of behavior, but they do influence more people than many of us think. Frankly, the only reason I'd listen to a God is due to 1 or 2 - otherwise, take a hike buddy!
Finally, we have (4), which is driven by empathy or duty, depending on what you feel the "right order of things" are (e.g., incarcerate or rehabilitate the drug addict?)
Again, except for (3), none of these necessarily need to appeal to some objective truth to have force - we merely have to assent to their goal.
The fact that we have different morals just reflects that we have different views on what is true and what is desirable and we have no higher court of appeal.
There are many instances where we must either agree to disagree or engage in conflict (legal, physical, or otherwise). Under relativism, this kind of conflict is inevitable. That may not be what we want but it is what appears to be the case.
Of course, this all hinges on how much you agree that this question is empirical at all, and if you'd really expect to see more homogeneity under moral realism. But to me I need to assume less to just accept that morals are not ultimately correct or incorrect, but helpful or unhelpful, given a particular goal. But there is no objective source of goals that we can point to.

"If there are objective morals, we'd expect it to manifest in some objective way in the world." - Can I ask why we would expect this?

@ConnieMnemonic -- objective => observer/subject independent => intersubjective agreement => common moral basis

@ConnieMnemonic if you deny step 2, then you basically saying its not objective, if you  deny step 3 then you are saying certain peoples are ignorant of the facts or in denial of the facts

@ConnieMnemonic finally, even if this entire chain were correct, it would establish that within the human species there appear to be objective moral sentiments we share - it's still a huge leap to then say -- and these are universally true for all sentient life in the universe

Interesting. Doesn't step 2 in your chain imply that objective morality can be "observed" though? Isn't that circular?

@ConnieMnemonic -- can you explain the circularity there? objective means that there is  intersubjective verifiability (e.g., like the sun is objectively in the sky)

I think we have a disagreement on the definition of objective. Objectively, there are particular rocks on planets far enough from us that we cannot observe them. This cannot be intersubjectively verified but it is the objective truth.

The circularity comes from the fact we are discussing whether objective morality would have observable effects in the world. If your argument tree presupposes the observability of objective morality, we're in a circle.

@ConnieMnemonic ah, ok -- yes, its true that objective doesn't mean observable by humans. But then its hard to verify that its objective isn't it? For example, "Liking chocolate is objectively correct." There, I've stated it is objective but in what sense can I back that up? Our only way is to appeal to intersubjectivity right or to some kind of logical consistency criteria?

That's not our only way. We don't need intersubjectivity to assert that we exist/are thinking and experiencing something. Cogito ergo sum. Arguably mathematics can be proven as objective without intersubjectivity, though I'm shakier here. As for things like morality, as a Catholic I also believe in divine revelation as a source of insight into objective truth, but of course that's a different conversation, heh heh.

@ConnieMnemonic we don't need intersubjectivity for oruselves almost by definition --we're self verifying :) as for math and morality, these are in a sense formal systems - you either accept their axioms or not (I'm a nominal catholic myself so here we'd accept what is in the Catechism)  - but nothing external to those systems compels us to accept the axioms. Contrast that with things like gravity, the sun, rocks, thorns in our toe -- those exist outside of our wants -- you can believe you can fly all you want but you will not.

@ConnieMnemonic what I feel moral realists lack is an analog to what we do in science to demonstrate realism/objectivity of a phenomenon. Or like in math where we take self evident (almost) axioms and show what must follow.

It's a tricky complaint! I'm a convert myself coming from atheism, so I feel you deeply here. Ultimately, what convinced me was personal experience. Perhaps one could argue that the saints and the Church, that the "witnesses" are the intersubjective yardstick; experiencing the transcendent, and discovering that others have also encountered the divine in very, very similar terms.

@ConnieMnemonic -- I can see that. Still atheist myself but I think one can rationally hold theistic views. My spouse is a believing Catholic and they would agree with your view on the importance of personal relationship with God and the authority of the Church. It's just that I don't happen to agree (but am not dismissive either)

Ride safe, friend. It's a strange world we live in! God bless, this was a cool interaction.

If stealing is wrong then why do thieves exist? If light and darkness are different, then why are some people blind?

@Matthias -- very poetic :) so do you agree with relativism, realism, or are just confused like the rest of us?

@Annika about being "confused" I don't know how to answer. I believe that God said certain things so that makes me a realist. But about confusion -- I understand some things, some things I don't, and some things I believe but don't see.
